# configurable virtual product magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to have a configurable product in my shop where the "associated products" are virtual. I set up my configurable product with simple products before, but it is a "subscription" oriented product and I need the virtual product functionality.

The way I set it up before was to create the configurable product first and then add the simple products from the configurable product creation screen, but there is no option there for virtual products. I did not see any other way to add the "associated" products after quite a bit of searching.

Comment: Are you certain that your virtual products have attributes which are and can be used for configurable products? Check the attributes you want to include and make sure that they too can be applied to virtual products.

Comment: Silly of me, I thought the attributes would be added afterwards. I was able to create my product! Too bad you didn't write this as an answer, so I could mark it as correct :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was fixed by first creating three virtual products using the attribute set that I wanted to use for the configurable product. I was then able to create a configurable product and find the virtual products at the bottom of the "Associated Products" section after clicking "Reset Filters." The virtual products then appeared in the Super Product Attributes section and I was able to set up the configurable product.